# WCF Compatible Service Running on Linux

Tags: linux, wcf, gsoap

I am designing an interface that allows a .NET client to communicate with our hardware. The hardware is running a flavor of Embedded Linux, and the firmware team plans to use lighttpd for a Web Server, and gSOAP for a SOAP based web service. Also the firmware team does not plan to use Mono. The majority of code on the hardware will be C/C++.

I am working on the client end which will be a .NET 4.5 application. I am wanting to utilize WCF on the client side.

I am having a difficult time trying to find any information on how to do this. According the gSOAP documentation it is WCF compatible.

Will this approach work? I am concerned about whether the SOAP base service implemented on the hardware will be compatible with WCF.

Comment: I think SOAP is a standard, or let's say an interface ... Any implementation using the same SOAP version should work. In my compagny we have implemented a C++ gSOAP interface that is is called from php::soap and it works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How do I determine the correct SOAP version? I think I read somewhere WCF uses 1.1, but gSOAP defaults to 1.2.

Comment: By sniffing the communication and checking the SOAP message (http://wso2.com/library/articles/differentiating-between-soap-versions-looking-soap-message/) However, SOAP 1.2 is out there since 2003, I strongly suggest to use it!